# How to find the number of occurrences of each digit in a random integer?

Tags: c++

I've made a simple random program that generates a random number between 0 and 9

```
int random_x;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
 srand ( time(NULL) );

for (int t=0;t<10;t++)
{ 
    random_x = rand() % 10; //generate 10 random integers between 0 and 10
    cout << "\n" << random_x;
}
```

The next stage is to set up an integer array to count how many of each digit occurs. For example if the random numbers are 144566888, then the output would be

```
1 appears 1 time 
4 appears 2 times
5 appears 1 time
6 appears 2 times
8 appears 3 times
```

This is what I've attempted but it returns "digit occurs 0 times"

```
int count[random_x] = {0};

while ( random_x > 0) {  //loop to return how many times a number appears
    count[ random_x % 10]++;
     random_x =  random_x / 10;
     cout <<"Digit occurs: " << random_x << " times" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that your generating 10 random numbers but included only 9 in your example. Also, what you require would be to find the distinct elements in your array and the count/frequency of each.

Comment: @Anirban166 How would i go about doing this? Im unsure

Comment: You can use an `unordered_set` to store the unique values and count the occurences in an array given by the size of the set. Are you held by some time complexity constraints? This can be achieved in two loops but complexity would be quadratic. If bound to use an optimized logic I prefer the first way. (It stores unique elements)

Comment: @Anirban166 No I have no time constraints

Comment: Alright then, I'll write a solution soon wait.

Comment: @Anirban166 Okay thankyou

Comment: Try my updated code. Note that you can't use syntax like `int array[n]={value}` and expect all values of `array[n]` to be initialized with `value`.

Comment: @Anirban166: while that may be true for non-zero `value`, I believe `int arr[10] = {0};` *will* set all elements to zero. I've asked for clarification from the SO swarm :-), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61053225/does-c-zero-initialise-integers-in-an-array-like-c

Comment: @paxdiablo Ah I see..I was using `arr[9]={-1}` and that didn't work to set up all values, but I should have tried with `{0}`. (Didn't realize 0 was a special case) Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: No probs, it's only a special case by accident, really. `int arr[9] = {-1}` is guaranteed to set all the other elements to zero, it's just a happy coincidence if you use `0` instead of `-1` that they'll *all* be set to zero.

Comment: @paxdiablo 'Happy coincidence' xD  
   And yes, it makes sense now, that by default the values will be 0 unless we explicitly set them to other values within `{}`. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is just to keep an array of counts (initially all zero) and just update them as each digit is generated. Then, at the end, output those counts.

Something like this would be a good start:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr));

    // Count accumulators, all originally zero.

    int count[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { // or 'int count[10] = {0}' above.
        count[i] = 0;
    }

    // Process random digits, printing and accumulating.

    std::cout << "Generating random digits:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int digit = rand() % 10;
        std::cout << " " << digit;
        count[digit]++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Output the statistics.

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (count[i] == 1) {
            std::cout << "    Digit " << i << " occurs 1 time.\n";
        }
        else if (count[i] > 0) {
            std::cout << "    Digit " << i << " occurs " << count[i] << " times.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, the output for a few runs is:

```
Generating random digits: 6 1 5 8 9 2 8 0 5 3
    Digit 0 occurs 1 time.
    Digit 1 occurs 1 time.
    Digit 2 occurs 1 time.
    Digit 3 occurs 1 time.
    Digit 5 occurs 2 times.
    Digit 6 occurs 1 time.
    Digit 8 occurs 2 times.
    Digit 9 occurs 1 time.

Generating random digits: 3 4 0 1 3 3 9 9 5 7
    Digit 0 occurs 1 time.
    Digit 1 occurs 1 time.
    Digit 3 occurs 3 times.
    Digit 4 occurs 1 time.
    Digit 5 occurs 1 time.
    Digit 7 occurs 1 time.
    Digit 9 occurs 2 times.

Generating random digits: 7 7 9 7 3 7 4 3 7 4
    Digit 3 occurs 2 times.
    Digit 4 occurs 2 times.
    Digit 7 occurs 5 times.
    Digit 9 occurs 1 time.
```

Comment: In the output that OP gave, only distinct elements are mentioned with their respective count. Your `count[10]` stores the count for dupes as well, so I suppose this is not what is required.

Comment: Ive ran this code and it comes up with Digit occurs 0 times.

Comment: @David, it appears you didn't combine it properly into your own. The code you added to your question will  not work because you need to evaluate all random numbers and *afterward* output the whole count array. In any case, there was a misunderstanding on my part about the source of the number (one big number rather than lots of one-digit numbers) so I've now changed it to a complete self-contained program (with output as well) to better show you what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem pertains to counting the occurrences of each *unique* digit in the array.

There are different approaches to this, and one would be to use an `unordered_set` (which stores unique values) to store the distinct elements and take the count of the total number of unique elements to get the array size so we can allot a counter for each distinct element.

Since your not bound by time constraints, its easier to implement two loops, outer one going through all the elements and the inner one checking for dupes first (using an array to check frequency status) and counting occurence of each unique element seperately. (then the count value is transferred to the frequency holding array and values are printed accordingly at each iteration)

```cpp
// your rng-based digits in an array:
int a[9]={1,4,4,5,6,6,8,8,8};

// For checking unique/distinct digits first, and later on to hold the frequency as transferred by count:
int frequency[9]={-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};

    // Our counter variable, but counts will be transferred to frequency[] later on:
    int count;

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {   // Each distinct element occurs once atleast so initialize to one:
        count = 1;
        for(int j=i+1; j<9; j++)
        {
            // If dupe is found: 
            if(a[i]==a[j])
            {
                count++;

                // Ensuring not to count frequency of same element again:
                frequency[j] = 0;
            }
        }

        // If frequency of current element is not counted:
        if(frequency[i] != 0)
            frequency[i] = count;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        if(frequency[i] != 0)
            printf("%d appears %d times\n", a[i], frequency[i]);
    }
```