# Does C++ zero-initialise unspecified values during aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

An interesting question arose as a side effect of some other question here, about the possible differences between how C and C++ handle (the non-static-storage-duration):

```
int arr[7] = {0};
```

Someone was stating that, in C++, the other elements were not guaranteed to be zero but I'm not sure I agree.

Now C11 states, in `6.7.9 Initialization /19`:

> The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject; ***all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.***

This means that the other six elements of `arr` *will* be initilised to zero (since `static int x;` would initialise `x` to zero).

---

I'm unsure if this is also the case for C++. In the C++20 standard, `9.3.1 Aggregates /3` states:

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list as specified in `9.3.4`, the elements of the initializer list are taken as initializers for the elements of the aggregate. The explicitly initialized elements of the aggregate are determined as follows:
>
> (3.1) — (irrelevant stuff to do with designated initialiser lists and classes - pax).
>
> (3.2) — If the initializer list is an initializer-list, the explicitly initialized elements of the aggregate are the first `n` elements of the aggregate, where `n` is the number of elements in the initializer list.

Then `/4` states how the *explicit* initialisations work, and `/5` handles the non-explicit cases:

> For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly initialized element is initialized as follows:
>
> (5.1) — If the element has a default member initializer (10.3), the element is initialized from that initializer.
>
> (5.2) — Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list (9.3.4).
>
> (5.3) — Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

It appears to me that our particular case is covered by `(5.2)` so we have to go to `9.3.4` to see what happens to an `int` initialised with an empty list (`{}`). This goes through a lot of cases but I believe the first one that matches is:

> (3.11) — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

And, from `9.3 Initializers /8`:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> (8.1) — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 10) with either no default constructor (10.3.4) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
>
> (8.2) — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;
>
> (8.3) — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>
> (8.4) — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Hence, it's `8.4` which seems to be the controlling clause, meaning C++ will *also* initialise the non-explicit elements of the array to zero.

Is my reasoning correct? Will C++, on encountering `int arr[7] = {0};`, set all elements to zero?

Comment: "*Someone was stating that, in C++, the other elements were not guaranteed to be zero*" Where was this said?

Comment: `int arr[7] = {0};` will explicitly initialize the first element to zero, then the compiler will add code to initialize the remaining elements to zero.

Comment: Short answer: **Yes**

Comment: @NicolBolas: on rereading the comment, they *actually* stated that `int arr[n]={value}` didn't guarantee that all elements would be `value`. So, they're correct for `value != 0` but, since I *was* using `{0}` as the init list, I thought it strange. I just wanted clarification since ISO C++ is *so* much more headache-inducing than ISO C :-)

Comment: My understanding is "yes" - your reasoning and tracking through current (draft?) standard seems appropriate.    Although recent standards have made things more complicated,  the answer was also unambiguously "yes" in the 1998 C++ standard - and I would be very surprised if a subsequent standard would quietly change that, since a lot of existing code would break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. C++ generally maintains backward compatibility with C, allowing you to include and use C code. Consider if you have some legacy C code, that attempts to initialize an array like you describe:

`int arr[7] = {0};`

If C++ worked any differently, and the C program (validly, under C) assumed that this array is zero initialized, then the code is liable to fail if included in a C++ project compiled with a C++ compiler.

Just to confirm, I compiled this C++ program using Cygwin g++ on x64 Windows:

```
int main() {
    int arr[7] = {0};
}
```

and then disassembled function `main` in GDB:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
sub    $0x40,%rsp
callq  0x1004010d0 <__main>
movq   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
movq   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
movq   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)
movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
mov    $0x0,%eax
add    $0x40,%rsp
pop    %rbp
retq
```

As you can see, the program moves 3 qwords and 1 dword worth of zeros into the stack. That's 28 bytes, which is the size of 7 ints on my system.

Comment: Actually, that makes sense. While it doesn't maintain *perfect* backward compatibility (eg: `int new = 7;`, though I guess you're covered there since you used the word "generally"), code that you wanted to use in both C and C++ would most definitely be useless if the arrays were initialised differently.

Comment: Looking at compiler with "expected" behavior doesn't confirm behavior. C++ has too many UB, unspecified behavior, implementation-defined behavior to conclude from that. It is just an hint. That hint be be enforced by multiplying compilers and compiler options (especially turn on optimization).

Comment: Jarod42 In any case we still have evidence from the standard itself and reasoning about C backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

An extremely late additional answer in order to add a quite official reference here:

cppreference (for C) with [Array initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) has a clear example for this:

```
int a[3] = {0}; // valid C and C++ way to zero-out a block-scope array
int a[3] = {}; // invalid C but valid C++ way to zero-out a block-scope array
```

So things for your concrete example are totally clear.

> Someone was stating that, in C++, the other elements were not
> guaranteed to be zero but I'm not sure I agree.

That's simply wrong. As of the same reference:

> All array elements that are not initialized explicitly are
> zero-initialized

The C++ standard would have to mark this missing downward-compatibility explicitly but it doesn't. But as of http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-16.5 for C++ with abstraction to aggregates:

> The remaining elements are initialized with their default member
> initializers, if any, and otherwise are value-initialized.

That is zero for integers, see [Zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization):

> If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral
> constant zero explicitly converted to T.

So `int a[3] = {0};` isn't actually a single statement for the compiler to say "write all elements to zero", but a two steps order: "Initialize the first element explicitly with this value (happen to be zero already), initialize the remaining elements according their default value initializers/default value initialization, that is zero for int".

The reason why there's a bit confusion here might be the fact, that the C++ standard drafts for the C-adaption made several things quite abstract. So many programmers might think of value initialization for the remaining elements could be of the same quality like leaving variables/members non-initialized, but that's not true.

Also be aware, that the static duration case is an extra-topic here...